# Predictive Maintenance - Top books involving any domain

Tags: machine-learning, books

After working with predictive maintenance using ML algorithms for a while, I felt like I needed more theoretical background. To do so, I started some courses, but they don't dig into the hole and just explain demo cases.

I started searching for books (in reddit mostly), but I feel like the books that I find are not that good.

Can someone list top books of predictive maintenance using machine learning?